# How to close fragment in fragment, when back button pressed?

Tags: java, android-studio, fragment, onbackpressed

The structure is like this.
viewPager2 -> MainFragment -> Fragment1 & Fragment2 & Fragment3

I made 3 pages ViewPager2. In ViewPager2(fragment), I made new Fragment.
I used FrameLayout at the 'MainFragment'.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() { 
@Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {     
    viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
}
});
```

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragment = new MainFragment(); 
ft.add(R.id.layout_frame,fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

The Fragment has button. The button enable to replace other Fragment like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment = new Fragment1();
    ft = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.layout_frame,fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
});
```

Here, I want to replace the Fragment1 to MainFragment or close Fragment1, when back pressed.

How can I apply this in code?

I just don't know well. I'm junior developer. I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Try to rephrase it.
Try to make clear where does the ViewPager live? Is it inside your MainFragment?
You want to replace Fragment1 with what?

Comment: ViewPager is in MainActivity. And I want to replace Fragment1 to MainFragment.

Comment: You want to replace Fragment1 with what?
From the code you show, it is not clear WHY you use a ViewPager.
Which fragments are loaded inside the ViewPager?